# context.getSystemService(UserManager.class) returns null on Android 9 with Huawei phones

Tags: android, androidx, android-9.0-pie, huawei-mobile-services

Does someone knows the problem with Huawei phones running Android 9. It keeps returning null when trying to access :

```
context.getSystemService(UserManager.class)
```

The problem is that lot's of API relies on it like UserManagerCompat in androidx.core :

```
public static boolean isUserUnlocked(@NonNull Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        return context.getSystemService(UserManager.class).isUserUnlocked();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which leads to :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6737)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000 (ActivityThread.java:273)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2020)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:112)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.WebViewZygoteInit.main (WebViewZygoteInit.java:171)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at androidx.core.os.UserManagerCompat.isUserUnlocked (UserManagerCompat.java:1)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis (FirebaseApp.java:1)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:1)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (FirebaseApp.java:1)
```

Any workaround ?

Comment: I've filled https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146535388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Andris Answer, Huawei seem to respond correctly to :

```
Context.getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE)
```

And not to :

```
Context.getSystemService(UserManager.class)
```

So I had to override `Application#getSystemServiceName(Class<?> clazz)` to make `UserManagerCompat.isUserUnlocked(Context context)` work on buggy Huawei phones :

```
@Override
public String getSystemServiceName(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P
            && "huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
        String systemServiceName = super.getSystemServiceName(serviceClass);
        if (systemServiceName == null && UserManager.class.equals(serviceClass)) {
            systemServiceName = Context.USER_SERVICE;
        }
        return systemServiceName;
    }
    return super.getSystemServiceName(serviceClass);
}
```

This was possible because FirebaseApp is using `Context#getApplicationContext()` when available...

Comment: Is it for huawei manufacturer only or HMS-based devices? not able to reproduce it properly @avianey

Comment: Huawei phones with Google based Android

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing service class by service name :

```
public static boolean isUserUnlocked(@NonNull Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        return ((UserManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE)).isUserUnlocked();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt casting the returned service will change the fact that it is null...

Comment: Implementation of UserManager service get there is different. Maybe it is the thing, what differs in Huawey phones.

Comment: will try :thumbup: